# One word for "ask advice", "seek counsel"

Tags: single-word-requests

> I hope I can _____ your experience/wisdom/intuition.

Is how I would like to use it.

What verb could fit here and carry the meaning of, "I hope I can ask you advice informed by your wisdom" for example. "Because of your wisdom, I hope you will grant me your advice."

It seems like "appeal to" almost fits, "query" also almost fits but doesn't have any "seeking advice" connotation (and might sound too interrogative?). For some reason I feel like "defer to" should fit.

Comment: Are multi-word responses also acceptable? If so, "benefit from," "be enriched by," "depend on." One might even use "enjoy," which can mean not only "take pleasure in" but "benefit from."

Comment: @AndyBonner I love "depend on", not sure if it's too expectant and/or makes it seem like all the responsibility is in their hands.

Comment: @AndyBonner Just wondering whether *depend on* is a bit like thanking someone in advance, puts pressure on the person, conveys expectation by the person asking, or assumes the person has already offered help.

Comment: @DjinTonic Oh, I certainly think it does. But so (in a subtler way) does "Because of your wisdom, I hope you will grant me your advice." theonlygusti, do you think you could edit in a bit more clarification of the tone you're going for? Is the emphasis more that the imparted wisdom is beneficial, or that it is likely to be given?

Comment: appeal to is fine. It actually fits.

Comment: For your specific "fill in the blank" context, *I hope I can **call upon** your experience/wisdom/intuition* is the most likely version. But based on the question title itself, perhaps ***consult*** is the word you're looking for. Note that at a pinch, ***consult*** can be used intransitively - *Your proposal looks good to me, but I'll need to consult before approving the project* (consult ***with other people*** relevant to the authorisation process).

Comment: It doesn’t answer the question but “seek” is the word that would fit “___ your knowledge” best.

Comment: *I hope I can **solicit** your wisdom.* [to seek for (something) by entreaty, earnest or respectful request, formal application, etc.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/solicit)

Comment: *glean* works in the sentence, but not as an answer to the question

Comment: I like *defer to* just fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about

**consult**

> to go to somebody for information or advice

or

**solicit**

> to ask somebody for something, such as support, money or information;
> to try to get something or persuade somebody to do something

[Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary]

Comment: "consult" nailed it

Comment: _consult_ someone's wisdom? That doesn't sound proper, though.

Comment: This does not work: *I hope I can consult your wisdom.*

Comment: Unlike „enlist your wisdom“ or „figure (on) your wisdom“ there are actual results on google books for „consult your wisdom“. And the more I read it, the more I like it. Also many examples for „solicit your wisdom“, surprisingly.

Comment: You can consult a person regarding an issue, and you can consult a tangible information source, such as a dictionary. However, you can't consult an intangible concept like wisdom.

Comment: You can solicit ("ask for", "request") wisdom. Muti-choice answers should always be separated for exactly this reason. I would upvote one word here, and downvote the other. You can add more than one answer to a question.

Comment: Why would I be able to consult a book but not wisdom? If wisdom is defined as: "[a body of] knowledge that is gained by having many experiences in life" [merriam webster], then, I feel that you should explain more in detail why it shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 7):

> I hope I can **enlist** your experience/wisdom/intuition.

**enlist** (v.)

> [*With object*] Engage (a person or their help or support)
>
> *The company enlisted the help of independent consultants* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/enlist)

> If you enlist the help of someone, you persuade them to help or
> support you in doing something.
>
> *I had to cut down a tree and enlist the help of seven neighbors to get it out of the yard!*  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/enlist)

---

> In your case, it is apparent that President Nixon could well
> **enlist your experience**, and your influence in Congress, to help rebuild the relationship of confidence and cooperation between
> President and Congress which should ... [letter from Eugene Rostow in
> US Congress; *Nomination of Gerald Ford to be Vice President*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nomination_of_Gerald_R_Ford_of_Michigan/gJ7LHk5a7_wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22enlist%20your%20experience%22&pg=PA17&printsec=frontcover)

> I particularly will not **enlist your aid** in solving my own
> problems. [Harold Rose; *Hypnotherapy in Clinical Psychiatry*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hypnotherapy_in_Clinical_Psychiatry/neQhAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22enlist%20your%20aid%22&dq=%22enlist%20your%20aid%22&printsec=frontcover)

> I would **enlist your knowledge, your ideas**, in securing for my
> people... [E. Flint and ‎G. Barber; *1636: Mission to the Mughals*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/1636_Mission_to_the_Mughals/Ac9KDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22enlist%20your%20knowledge%22&pg=PT545&printsec=frontcover)

> ... the Committee has long advocated the wisdom of **enlisting the
> assistance** of those organizations in effecting the wides possible
> dissmention of information relating to the process of decolonization.
> [*Studies on Developing Countries*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Studies_on_Developing_Countries/9hXsAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=enlisting%20his%20wisdom&dq=enlisting%20his%20wisdom&printsec=frontcover)

> For long, technical, or high stakes documents, **enlist** a partner to
> help with proofreading. [Ashan Hampton ; *Proofreading Power*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Proofreading_Power_Skills_Drills/-ZhoDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=enlist%20your%20to%20proofread&pg=PA24&printsec=frontcover)

> When done by the day, ask how many hours the driver considers a day to
> be; it might be only three or four. If your Spanish is weak,
> **enlist** a desk clerk to help you make the deal. [Carl Franz et al.; *The People's Guide to Mexico*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_People_s_Guide_to_Mexico/I2YZgJJXj1YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=enlist%20the%20desk%20clerk%27s%20help&pg=PA133&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Enlist implies more commitment (or even pushing unwelcome commitment) on the receiving end than consult...

Comment: @rackandboneman Not necessarily. I've added two examples to illustrate.

Answer (score 5):

**borrow**

> take (a word or idea) from another language, person, or source and use it in one's own language or work

from Oxford Dictionary of English.

I think idiomatically in this kind of context:

> I hope I can borrow your wisdom.

It also means something like "please share with me"/"please help me out"("can I borrow you?").

This word doesn't really mean "ask advice".

Comment: This is a very British way to ask for help

Answer (score 1):

**figure on (someone or something)**

> To depend or rely on someone or something

*I thought we could figure on your help with this event, but I guess not.*

*We were figuring on that tax refund to help get us through the next month.*

[The Free Dictionary]

Comment: That is very American-English rather than British-Englih I think.  Also, it sounds like a colloquialism?

Comment: It might be regional; it's not a phrase that I (an American) am familiar with at all.

Comment: I have rarely heard this used. I think *count on* is a more common expression in this context.

Comment: I live in the Midwestern US. I would understand this but it does sound casual and unprofessional, which may not be desired.

Comment: I agree with you all that it's rather anusaar uncommon phrase. _count on_ or _bank on_ are the more common expressions one uses.

Answer (score 1):

> I hope I can _____ your experience/wisdom/intuition.

A less formal word I don't see mentioned yet would be "tap".  It's usually employed as access to a reservoir of liquid but is reasonably colloquial to work as a reference to reservoirs of experience/wisdom/intuition.  In this context it also serves as a deferential term since it usually applies to large reservoirs.

Answer (score 0):

How about 'leverage on your experience'? Not sure your can say that. Can anyone tell me, please?
Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to the site! The question seems to be asking for a single-word answer. I guess “leverage” might fit in some contexts, although I would probably say “use” or “utilize,” but these words have a broader meaning.

Comment: I also would use *leverage* with a direct object, not say “leverage on,” in American English.

Answer (score 0):

[**Confer**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confer) with someone also works.

> to discuss something important in order to make a decision